# Php count multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays

here is my array :

```
$pid = array("id"=>array(
 "098"=> array(
              array("size"=>25,"variant"=>"0925","qty"=>1),
              array("size"=>26,"variant"=>"0926","qty"=>2)
            ),
 "099"=> array(
              array("size"=>25,"variant"=>"0726","qty"=>1)
            )
         )
       );
```

can i count how much that array with different id? can i count how much that size array per id?

i just wanna see like this :

```
ID = 2
size of 098 = 2
size of 099 = 1
```

Comment: You **cannot** have array with same keys. It is impossible.

Comment: @u_mulder why? i chose ways like this for my shopping cart bag, any other ways to do for that?

Comment: Think of it - if you have array with 2 same keys - what should be returned when you refer `$pid['id']['098']`? First value or second?

Comment: `"098" => array(array(...), array(...))`, this is one way of grouping the same  "id"

Comment: @u_mulder thank's for the information dude!

Comment: @Andrew omg ok i forget dude, thanks! i will try with thats

Comment: @Andrew i will edit my question now.. thanks

Comment: you are probably looking for `count($pid["id"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This corresponds to your array:

```
<?php
// Your array
$pid = array("id"=>array(
    "098"=> array(
        array("size"=>25,"variant"=>"0925","qty"=>1),
        array("size"=>26,"variant"=>"0926","qty"=>2)
    ),
    "099"=> array(
        array("size"=>25,"variant"=>"0726","qty"=>1)
    )
) );

// The relevant code
foreach ($pid as $id => $items) {
    echo $id . ' = ' . count($items) . '<br />';
    foreach ($items as $key1 => $item) {
        echo 'size of ' . $key1 . ' = ' . count($item) . ' <br />';
    }
}
?>
```

The result:

> id = 2
> size of 098 = 2
> size of 099 = 1

Answer (score 1):

**This Gives You desire Output..**

```
       echo 'ID ='.count($pid['id']);
        foreach ($pid['id'] as $key => $res) {
          echo 'size of ' .$key.'= ' .count($res);
         }
```

**Output**

> ID =2
>
> size of 098= 2
>
> size of 099= 1